# scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs works slower than linalg.eigvals even for large matrices

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I saw the quiestion here about **scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs** works slower than **linalg.eigvals**, but the problem was that there were small matrixes. In my case I have matrix 1000x1000, but linalg.eigvals is still performing much better as in code below:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse.linalg as lg

N = 1000
m = sp.sparse.random(N, N, density=0.05).tocsc()
a = m.A

%timeit lg.eigs(m, k=500, return_eigenvectors=False, which='LR', tol = 0.0001)

%timeit sp.linalg.eigvals(a)
```

3.62 s ± 520 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) For **eigs**

 1.68 s ± 420 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) For **eigvals**

I can't understand how is it possible

Comment: I'm not familiar with the limitations of the implicitly restarted Arnoldi method underlying `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`, but half the eigenvalues seems like a lot of eigenvalues to ask for.

Comment: Also, 5% may not be sparse enough for sparsity-based optimizations to pay off.